# How can a server application safely connect to a user-supplied IP address?

Tags: web-services, sockets, minecraft

I'm making a public web service with an "announce" endpoint, that allows users to supply a host+port on which they are hosting a multiplayer game (Minecraft). My service then connects to their game to get some info about it. The game protocol requires my service to send the initial handshake, and then wait for a proper reply.

Ideally, the game could be listening on any port above 1024, and on a host that is not necessarily the source of the announcement. If that cannot be done safely, I could potentially restrict to the game's standard port and/or the remote host of the announce request.

How can I do this in a safe way? What restrictions do I need to put on the host/port? Is there something special I should do when connecting to the game?

Comment: I suggest using Minecraft's built-in query capability, which supports the GameSpy 4 protocol. For examples, please refer to [here](http://wiki.vg/Query#Example_implementations).

Comment: Interesting.. but why is that superior to the status protocol on the main port? It's more work for the server admin to setup, it doesn't verify that the main port is reachable, and it doesn't have the server icon. That's probably why the Minecraft client doesn't use it.

Comment: “to get some info” was vague; I gave you what first came to mind; figuring that you'd want information on server version, plugins, game type, etc. However, now that you’ve provided more details it appears that you would like to issue a [Server List Ping](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping). As far as safety, it’s a simple web service request returning a JSON data structure. It isn’t any less safe than making similar web service requests via SOAP or REST.

Comment: Yes but such requests can indeed be dangerous, as discussed here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47548/how-dangerous-is-it-to-allow-arbitrary-webhook-urls-to-post-to

Comment: I’m at a loss how webhooks or similar techniques come into play during a simply query to a Minecraft server. Once you have a server IP address and port, your info gathering task is under your control. You establish a TCP connection, send a request, and wait for a response. Since the Server List Ping is a defined interface, you can quickly determine if the response is valid or not as data streams in. If anything is outside of accepted norms, you kill the connection. More details in your question, might eliminate this game of 20 Questions.

Comment: Allowing users to make a connection to any IP and port from the application server is not safe in general, as they are behind the firewall and have access to the local network. Conceivably, they could connect to some internal service and cause some unwanted side-effect, even if that service doesn't speak the Minecraft protocol.

Comment: Your “connection” fears are greater than the reality of it. The query process is **under your control**. It is a simple protocol and simple connection, telling you whether the destination is a Minecraft server or not. What you do with that information and how you handle abuse is part of your business/control logic, not the connection. Having reviewed past answers and questions of yours, I’m surprised this does not sink in. Best wishes on your project.